# I'm trying to install mumble but apparently I'm missing some dependencies

Tags: apt, mumble

I got the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mumble-server : Depends: libiceutil34 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libzeroc-ice34 but it is not installable  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I honestly have no clue how to solve this problem. I'm relatively new to Linux in general and Google provides answers way too complicated for my level of understanding.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the output of `sudo apt-get check` and `apt-cache policy`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to install mumble-server from a package that you downloaded from somewhere other than the default Ubuntu repositories. If this is the case, you can install mumble-server from the Ubuntu Software Center or from the terminal by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mumble-server
```

Or maybe you are trying to install mumble-server from a PPA. and the version of mumble-server that you are trying to install is not compatible with the versions of libiceutil34 and libzeroc-ice34 in the Ubuntu Software Center. The solution is to remove the PPA and install mumble-server from the default repositories in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge  # disables a PPA and reverts to official packages
sudo apt-get ppa-purge ppa:name-of-the-mumble-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mumble-server
```